# Share links for Facebook and LinkedIn (Drupal)

Tags: facebook, button, drupal, share, linkedin-api

I need to add Facebook and LinkedIn share buttons to site on Drupal. But the problem is that links does not recognized correctly.  It becomes from  http://example.com/#[node:title] to  http://example.com/, so node aliases is just being ignored.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why pay for a service to help you share links on social media when it's free and easy to do yourself?

**Facebook:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}
```

[**Official Facebook Sharer Documentation**](http://FaceBook:%20We%20have%20changed%20the%20behavior%20of%20the%20sharer%20plugin...)

**LinkedIn:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

**[Official LinkedIn Share URL Api Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)**

If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]